# elements are not in the $form after firing callback, in original module_form function the are and displaying

Tags: forms, ajax

I don't understand this one. I hope it is not something stupid. When the callback is fired, the form elements that need to be rebuilt are not in the $form anymore. This is quite strange, because they are in original module_form function and displaying.

The form elements are generated through an extra function, that is iteratively called from the module_form function. -> is that a problem?

I have tested this without the nested function and without the iteration and then it works fine. does someone has any idea?

```
        function mymodule_form($form, &$form_state) {
      $url1 = arg(1);
// container with the ajax elements
      $form['container']=array (
            '#prefix' => '<div id="kasten-images-div-images">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#type' => 'container',
            '#markup' => '',
            );
//container with the element that fire the ajax callback
      $form['container2']=array (
            '#prefix' => '<div id="kasten-images-div-radios">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            );
//iteration generating the ajax elements
      for ($i=0;$i<$url1;$i++){
            $j = $i +1;
            $exist = array_key_exists('values',$form_state);
            if($exist){
                $type_string = 'type'.$j;
                $test[$i]=empty($form_state['values'][$type_string]);
                } else {$test[$i]=true;}
            if($test[$i]){
                //show default ajax element(image) on load form
                $form = display_closet($j,'6',$form);
            }
            else {
                //show chosen element(image) with ajax
                $choice =$form_state['values'][$type_string];
                $form = display_closet($j,$choice,$form);
            }
        }
//iteration generating the elements that fire the ajax callback    
        for ($i=0;$i<$url1;$i++){
            $form = display_form_element($i,$form);
        }
//form submit
      $form['submit_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Ga naar Stap 4',
      );
      return $form;
    }

function mymodule_form_callback_1($form, $form_state){
    return $form['container']['image-field-1'];
}


function display_closet($j,$choice,$form){
    $image_field_string = 'image-field-'.$j;
    $prefix_string = '<div id="kasten-images-div-'.$j.'">';
    $address ='<img src="http://www.mysite.be/sites/default/files/var'.$choice.'.png">';
    $form['container'][$image_field_string]= array (
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => '<div class="my-class-2-image"><p>'.$address.'</p></div>',
        '#weight' => '-10',
        '#prefix' => $prefix_string,
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        );
        return $form;
}

function display_form_element($i,$form){
    $j = $i +1;
    $name = 'type'.$j;
    $imageOptions = array(
      "1" => '<img src="http://www.mysite.be/sites/default/files/var1_small.png" />',
      "2" => '<img src="http://www.mysite.be/sites/default/files/var2_small.png" />',
    );
    $form['container2'][$name] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#options' => $imageOptions,
        '#title' => 'Mymodule Kast '.$j.':',
        '#size' => 12,
        '#maxlength' => 10,
        '#required' => TRUE, //make this field required
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('my-class-1')),
        '#ajax' => array(
              'callback' => 'mymodule_form_callback_'.$j,
              'wrapper' => 'kasten-images-div-'.$j,
              'method' => 'replace',
              'effect' => 'fade',
              ),
    );
    return $form;
}
```

this is a var_dump of first container on loading the form, elements image-field-{i} are present:

```
    ["container"]=> array(7) 
{ ["#prefix"]=> string(35) "" 
["#suffix"]=> string(6) "" 
["#type"]=> string(9) "container" 
["#markup"]=> string(0) "" 
["image-field-1"]=> array(5) { ["#type"]=> string(6) "markup" ["#markup"]=> string(110) "" ["#weight"]=> string(3) "-10" ["#prefix"]=> string(30) "" ["#suffix"]=> string(6) "
    " } 
["image-field-2"]=> array(5) { ["#type"]=> string(6) "markup" ["#markup"]=> string(110) "" ["#weight"]=> string(3) "-10" ["#prefix"]=> string(30) "
    " ["#suffix"]=> string(6) "" } 
["image-field-3"]=> array(5) { ["#type"]=> string(6) "markup" ["#markup"]=> string(110) "
    " ["#weight"]=> string(3) "-10" ["#prefix"]=> string(30) "
    " ["#suffix"]=> string(6) "
    " } }
```

and this is a var_dump of the container in the callback-function, the image-field-{i} elements are not there anymore ...

```
["container"]=>
array(17) {
["#prefix"]=>
string(35) ""
["#suffix"]=>
string(6) ""
["#type"]=>
string(9) "container"
["#markup"]=>
string(0) ""
["#theme_wrappers"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(9) "container"
}
["#process"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(22) "form_process_container"
}
["#defaults_loaded"]=>
bool(true)
["#tree"]=>
bool(false)
["#parents"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(9) "container"
}
["#array_parents"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(9) "container"
}
["#weight"]=>
int(0)
["#processed"]=>
bool(true)
["#required"]=>
bool(false)
["#attributes"]=>
array(0) {
}
["#title_display"]=>
string(6) "before"
["#id"]=>
string(17) "edit-container--2"
["#sorted"]=>
bool(true)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! One of the comments says _container with the element that fire the ajax callback_, but I don't see #ajax being used. Please show all the code you are using, or we cannot tell you what is wrong in your code.

Comment: hello, this is all the code, check the ajax in the `function display_form_element($i,$form)`

Answer (score 0):

On both functions, you are returning the entire `$form` variable that will override your initial `$form` build on the beginning of your form, is that normal ?

I think you need to return just the element and assign this value into your form directly on the right key of your `$form` array.

Oy maybe you want to pass your form by reference and add some elements directly. Something is missing for sure.

You can use `dpm()` if you have Devel to show the final `$form` structure.

**EDIT:** well I just saw you were passing the full $form, so it may works, the logic behind it is kinda weird for me. But what I said is not totally correct.

Comment: I have tried to returning only changed $form on both function, but still in callback functions the $form ajax elements are missing, they are loading and displaying perfectly

Comment: @user7715658 There is no need to pass `$form` to the function, and get it back from it. If I need `my_function()` to add form elements, I just pass [`$form` by reference](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging I have found the answer, quite stupid but now I know, lies in the second line:

```
$url1 = arg(1);
```

This is ok for the form load, but for the ajax, it does not fly, so this variable doesn't get properly set, therefore all iterations don't work, since this variable is in the for statement for the iterations.
I solved it by putting this variable in the $_SESSION variable.